# Android - NO SUCH TABLE

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-sqlite

Why is my Notes table not creating, can anyone see any error in my query string. I have figured out that I wasnt inputting data into my notes table cause it doesnt exist.

```
    private static final String CREATE_NOTES = "CREATE TABLE "
        + NOTE_TABLE + "("
        + NOTES_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
        + FK_ID + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_DATE + " DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,"
        + COLUMN_TITLE + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
        + COLUMN_BODY + " TEXT, "
        + " FOREIGN KEY ("+FK_ID+") REFERENCES "+USER_TABLE+" ("+COLUMN_ID+"));";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
   //Deletes database
   // context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

   db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS);
   db.execSQL(CREATE_NOTES);
}
```

Comment: i think data is not inserted in your db

Comment: @Ravi it displays the toast so I though tit would have been?

Comment: but there may be chance that db insertion fail,Try to debug insert statement and print row count (insert statement returns a rou count)in log to verify data inserted successfully.

Comment: @Ravi okay I found out the Notes table doesnt exist, can you check my code why it isnt creating ill update it now

Answer (score 0):

Do something like below example -

```
public class DatabaseHelperextends SQLiteOpenHelper{

       private static DatabaseHelper mDatabaseHelper;

       public DatabaseHelper(Context context) {
         super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        //Deletes database
       // context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
      }

      public static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context){
        if(mDatabaseHelper==null){
          mDatabaseHelper= new DatabaseHelper(context);
        }
        return mDatabaseHelper;
      }

      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        db.execSQL(CREATE_USERS);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_NOTES);
      }

 }
```

and call getInstance() method before your insert statement.

```
DatabaseHelper mHelper = DatabaseHelper.getInstance() ;
mHelper.insert();
```

it will create new database if not exist.

Comment: I have fixed the issue of creating a table, but Im trying to get the user's unique data through their id. How can I compared the logged in user's id to the FK user ID.